# is flutter have concept like android "addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)"

Tags: flutter

I have two pages:
1 - Store List
2 - Filter Screen

i want to do

1. by click filter icon of Store List = start Filter Screen
2. by click apply button of filter screen = start Store List
3. on back press i want go to the home screen

in store list page i want do this :

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    var route = MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => FilterScreen(areaList));
                        Navigator.of(context).push(route);
  },
  child: new Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: new Image.asset(
      "images/ic_filter.png", 
      height: 30.0, 
      width: 30.0)),
),
```

in Filter screen i was do this:

```
new Expanded(
  child: new MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {
      String areaIds = "";
      for(int i=0;i<areaList.length;i++){
        if(areaList[i].isChecked){
        areaIds += "${areaList[i].AreaMasterId},";
        }
        }
//           Constants.areaMasterIds = areaIds;
//           Constants.isLoadingAllStore = true;
    var route = new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new AllStoreTabScreen(false));
     Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(route);

                },
                color: Colors.myColor,
                child: new Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "APPLY",
                    style: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .body1
                        .apply(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? On SO, you should show your existing code and the problems you have, not only a list of requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is no, Flutter has no mechanism for this because under the hood there is only one `Activity` on Android.

Now to deal with the problem you describe. It just requires simple use of the `Navigator`. Intro for beginners [here](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/).

It sounds like you have three pages: `home`, `StoreList`, and `FilterScreen`. You start on the home screen, go to the store list, a user might filter the list or return to the home screen.

To get to the FilterScreen, add this to the button in StoreList:

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FilterList()),
  );
}
```

When you are ready to go back to the StoreList, just use `Navigator.pop(context)`.

Comment: i found solution of this from here https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/returning-data/